# Spring Boot treat 404 as regular exception

Tags: spring-boot

Rather than have an error page for a 404 I'd like to treat it like a normal exception in my Spring Boot application.  Is there any way to treat the 404 errors as an exception instead of having it forward to the `/error` page.

My overall goal is basically to treat this using my existing:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyClass {

  @ExceptionHandler (...)
  public ResponseEntity<?> doStuff(Throwable t) {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Spring doesn't throw exception when page/resource is not found (`NoHandlerFoundException`), so there is nothing to handle. 
You can override this behaviour by switching this configuration property to true:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

After that you can implement your own handler for `NoHandlerFoundException`.